# How many validator nodes on cardano

Tags: cardano-node, node, decentralization

How many validator nodes are there that verify 1 transaction block on cardano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question is a little confused/confusing.

So far (at mainnet chain tip), there are over 2500 block producers that have created at least one block.

For epoch 329 (last complete epoch) there were 1102 distinct block producers.

Does that answer your question?